# asdf ruby install 3.1.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oh-my-zsh, asdf

I have ruby as well as asdf installed on my macOS and the following error(?) comes up sporadically. I simply ignore the message and continue my work but is there a solution to this?

When I type "ruby -v" it gives "ruby 3.1.2p20". When I go to my .tool-versions file it has ruby 3.1.2. Is there a setting somewhere I'm missing? I am also using zsh as well as oh-my-zsh.

```
No preset version installed for command colorls
Please install a version by running one of the following:

asdf install ruby 3.1.2

or add one of the following versions in your config file at 
ruby 3.0.3
```

I typed 'rails -v' and a similar message comes up.

```
No preset version installed for command rails
Please install a version by running one of the following:

asdf install ruby 3.1.2

or add one of the following versions in your config file at /Users/zachariasn/.tool-versions
ruby 2.7.4
ruby 3.0.3
```

Comment: Try running `asdf reshim ruby`. If it does not work try installing those gems again for that Ruby version.